# What is SSL and how does it relate to HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, https

What is SSL and how does it relate to HTTPS?

Answer (score 29):

SSL is the secure socket layer, a cryptographic protocol to encrypt network traffic.  The most recent version of SSL is version 3, which fixed some known issues in SSLv2.  HTTPS is HTTP over SSL... or HTTP over TLS.

[TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) (Transport Layer Security) is the successor to SSLv3 and is largely replacing SSLv3 as the default HTTPS protocol in web browsers and servers.

As a side note, HTTPS usually listens on port 443, rather than port 80.

Comment: As a side note, as of this writing TLS has 3 versions: 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2.  Also, since this was posted SSLv3 support has been deprecated in most browsers due to security issues.

Answer (score 11):

HTTPS is just HTTP over SSL.  Or Hypertext Transfer Protocol over Secure Socket Layer.

SSL is an encrypted channel for communication.  HTTP is the way to transfer web pages and other web content across the network.

Answer (score 6):

**HTTPS:** (RFC 2818) is for providing secure communication. It is an application layer protocol on TCP/IP stack (similar to HTTP).

**SSL:** It is a layer in TCP/IP Stack between Application layer and Transport layer. It mentions client-server authentication (it is done through a handshake and certificate based authenticvation) adhering to PKCS (public key crypto standards); communication of messages over the secure channel once it was established (certain agreed crypto standards are used to enforce proper encryption/decryption at sending and receiving side). In summary, no application data are sent unless an authenticated, encrypted channel is established.

**Relation b/w SSL and HTTPS:** HTTPS is secure HTTP communication based on SSL protocol (HTTP over SSL, as they say). Generally all sensitive info (like passwords, financial details, etc.) are sent over this transport. Common example: your gmail login is done through HTTPS channel.

**Miscellaneous:**  Almost all standard browsers support https. You can see the certificates they possess by default. SSLV2, SSLV3 and TLS are the supported standards (as far as I recollect).

Answer (score 4):

**HTTPS = HTTP over SSL**

SSL is a layer over TCP that allows for secure, encrypted exchange of data.

HTTP normally runs over TCP and is therefore not encrypted.  HTTPS is where the HTTP protocol is run over SSL rather than directly over TCP and therefore the data exchanged is encrypted.

Answer (score 3):

> Think of an SSL Certificate as being a safe encrypted channel to
>   transmit data over the web.
>
> The SSL (Secure Socket Layer) creates an encoded connection between a
>   web server and a web browser, protecting sensitive, personal data that
>   are recorded by a website, such as: credit card info, login info
>   (username & password), contact info. In this way it allows for safe
>   transfer of data on the web and ensures that no data will be stolen,
>   altered or falsified.
>
> The SSL Certificate has two specific functions:
>
> 1. **Authentication and Verification**: The SSL Certificate contains information about the accuracy of the ID of the person or company that
>      has requested its issuance. Visitors are able to verify the website’s
>      identity by clicking on the browser’s padlock symbol on the
>      characteristic trust mark (e.g. the Norton™ Secured Seal). The
>      inspection performed by the Certificate Authorities about whether or
>      not an SSL Certificate should be issued, is very strict and varies
>      according to the type of the Certificate.
> 2. **Data Encryption**: Encryption is the process behind SSL Certificates that allows for the safe transfer of data (numbers, text
>      or files) through the web. During the exchange of this data, the
>      information is encrypted in such a way, that a third party can’t
>      access or read the data without the encryption “key”.

Read More: **[The Ultimate Guide to SSL Certificates (2017 Update)](http://ssladvice.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-ssl-certificates/)**

Answer (score 1):

SSL is a protocol for secure tunneling or encrypting network connections at the application level.

HTTPS is just HTTP used over SSL.

Answer (score 1):

SSL and HTTPS are used for encrypted, secure network communications.  There are plenty of resources on the web that explain the protocols. 
Here is a link to one resource: http://www.ourshop.com/resources/ssl.html

Answer (score 0):

SSL Security(Secure Sockets Layer) is a technology which is used to secure data, transferred between two system i.e Server and client or between two different server. It uses encryption algorithms to scramble data in transit, preventing hackers from reading it as it is sent over the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Let me boil it to simple terms  :

- it's a simple file lies on the server
- SSL certificate is given by high authorities (eg. Amazon , goDaddy)

to the websites for making it more secure and to assure user and browser that we are protected.

Why do the websites need these certificates?

- Because user and most of the browser prefer secured websites (websites certified with SSL) over other ones?
- For data protection purpose
- Nowadays data security holds highest priority

> as other folks mentioned abv:   HTTP + SSL = HTTPS