# How does SSL actually encrypt information?

Tags: ssl, https

I just recently set up SSL on my website's account creation page.  I'm looking to expand this further to my entire site.

I had a question, though.  How does SSL encryption actually work and protect data in transit?  Furthermore, what methods are normally available to hackers to intercept data sent in plain-text over HTTP?  I know there is "sniffing", but that is always the only method given, there is never any elaboration.  Is there a way to examine the data being sent over HTTP and HTTPS? To compare and contrast?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/313394/62576) and the links contained in the first answer might help. This isn't really a programming question, though; it's a networking question, and Google could probably provide many sites offering explanations, like [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) found as the first result with a search for `SSL encryption`.

Comment: There are a number of similar questions on Security.SE, for example: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/6290/2435

Comment: @KenWhite, I'd say that sort question can be on topic (although it's better on Security.SE), simply because knowing how SSL/TLS works and where it sits with HTTPS can lead to better (more secure) programming. In addition, googling for SSL encryption can also lead to a number of misleading answers, not least pages from CAs, a number of which incorrectly associate the size of the encryption keys to the type of certificate.

Comment: For more details, there's [this recent question](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/20803/2435) too.

Comment: It is defined in the RFC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446

Comment: If you want to learn how encryption works, start with the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography#Modern_cryptography

Answer (score 18, accepted):

HTTP is not encrypted in any way.  Any network sniffer that can sniff the packets between the HTTP client and server (most network adapters support a promiscuous mode for this purpose) can view the HTTP data.

HTTPS data, on the other hand, is HTTP data that is encrypted with SSL/TLS.  SSL/TLS encrypts outbound data before it hits the network, and decrypts inbound data after being leaves the network.  There is no plain text on the network, so it doesn't matter if the packets are sniffed by a third-party.  Without the encryption keys, the sniffed data is garbage.  During the SSL/TLS handshake, the client and server negotiate encryption keys, certificates, etc with each other before any application data can then be exchanged.  Data that is sent to the server is encrypted using the server's key, and data sent to the client is encrypted using the client's key. This ensures that encrypted data sent by the client can only be decrypted by the server, and vice versa.

About the only way to intercept and extract plain text from a SSL/TLS encrypted connection is with a man-in-the-middle attack.  This means the SSL client connects to the MITM, and then the MITM connects to the SSL server, and funnels data back and forth between them.  The MITM needs access to the network that the client or server are running on, and has to be able to reroute the client's connection to itself instead of the server.  But if it can do that, the MITM can negotiate its own SSL/TLS connections with both parties so it has all of the necessary encryption information.  It can then receive and decrypt the SSL client's sent data using the encryption keys it negotiated with the SSL client, then re-encrypt and pass that data to the SSL server using the encryption keys it negotiated with the SSL server.  And vice versa.  The SSL client and SSL server will not know they are talking to a MITM instead of each other, unless you use certificates so the SSL client and SSL server can verify each other's identity during the initial handshake.  SSL/TLS does not require certificates, but they are good to use if you have them.

Comment: This is no answer to the question how encryption works.

Comment: @ceving the technical details of how encryption actually works is a bit too vast to answer here, there are whole books and research papers on the subject.

Comment: It does not even try to explain how it works. It explains, how it is used and what benefit it has. The "answer" is as off-topic as the question.

Comment: @ceving how does *the entire 2nd paragraph* not try to answer the actual question asked of "*How does SSL encryption actually work and protect data in transit*"? What is your logic here?