# SSL channel is encrypted or data

Tags: ssl, encryption, https

I just started working on TLS/SSL(Secure Sockets Layer) related projects.

I happen to read a lot of documents related to SSL for getting comfortable for the project and at some point, it struck me that "While the client and server is connected for communications after the handshake, it said that a secure channel is created between the client and the server for all the communications of a session".

My doubt is, whether the secure channel created between the client and server itself is encrypted and the data transferred through that secure channel is plain text? or the channel is secure but not encrypted and only the data sent through that secure channel is encrypted?"

Some say that "SSL is an encrypted secure channel" and others say "Secure channel is created and the data is encrypted" which puts me in the situation to post this question

I read lot of documents to get clarified but the more i read, the more confused i am.

Comment: I genuinely don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Seems to be encrypted https://stackoverflow.com/a/313394/2375207

Comment: "Then, shalt thou count to three. No more. No less. Three shalt be the number thou shalt count, and the number of the counting shall be three. Four shalt thou not count, nor either count thou two, excepting that thou then proceed to three. Five is right out. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to see it like this:

whenever you create a secure channel in this type of context, you create 2 endpoints...

whatever you stuff into the one endpoint comes out of the other ... what you put in may be plain text and it will come out as plain text ...

but what happens between the two endpoints ... that is subject of the actual protocol ... in this context something like "SSL is an encrypted secure channel" or "Secure channel is created and the data is encrypted" just describes features of the protocol, meaning that the stuff that happens between the two endpoints is ... encrypted ... secured against replay ... secured against unnoticed modification ... etc

if you have a setup like this:

SENDER -> X -> SSL Endpoint 1 -> Y -> SSL Endpoint 2 -> Z -> RECEIVER

when you look at X, you can see plain text
when you look at Y, you can see encrypted messages
when you look at Z, you can see plain text again